# How can I prove that the complement of the set of linear combinations of numbers with gcd 1 is finite?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $g_1,\ldots,g_n$ be natural numbers with gcd 1. Define $Q=\{a_1g_1+\cdots+a_ng_n| a_i\in\mathbb{N}\}$, what is the simplest way to prove that $\mathbb{N}\backslash Q$ is finite?

Comment: Just to be sure: do you mean that $\gcd\{g_1,\ldots,g_n\}=1$, or do you mean that the numbers $g_1,\ldots,g_n$ are **pairwise** relatively prime?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The former, I presume - otherwise we could even restrict to $a_3=\ldots=a_n=1$.

Comment: @Hagen: I expect it to be the former, but I want to be sure.

Comment: I meant gcd$\{g_1,\ldots,g_n\}=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I claim that any natural number $t$ larger than $(g_1+\dots+g_n)^2$ is in $Q$. (The bound here is excessive, but all that matters is that it's finite.)  Since the gcd of the $g_i$'s is 1, we can express $1$ and therefore also $t$ as a linear combination of the $g_i$'s with integer coefficients; the problem is to get those coefficients to be non-negative.

Start with any expression for $t$ as a linear combination of the $g_i$'s with integer coefficients. We're done if there are no negative coefficients, so assume some particular $g_i$, say $g_1$ without loss of generality, has a negative coefficient $a_1$. I claim that one of the other $g_j$'s must have a coefficient that is (not only positive but) larger than or equal to $g_1$.

To prove this claim, suppose it were false, so all the positive terms in our linear combination have the form $a_jg_j$ with $a_j<g_1$. But then all the positive terms together add up to at most $g_1(g_1+\dots+g_n)$, which is way smaller than our $t$. The negative terms only make things worse, so we have a contradiction and the claim is proved.

Fix some $j$ as in the claim.  Now we modify our expression for $t$, as a  linear combination of the $g_i$'s with integer coefficients, by subtracting $g_1$ from the coefficient $a_j$ of $g_j$ (which, by our choice of $j$ leaves that coefficient still non-negative) and adding $g_j$ to the (negative) coefficient $a_1$ of $g_1$. We still have a correct expression for $t$, because we added and subtracted $g_1g_j$. But there's less negativity than before; more precisely, we've decreased the sum of the absolute values of the negative coefficients. Repeat the process until that sum reaches $0$ and there are no longer any negative coefficients.

(I've assumed that $\mathbb N$ contains $0$. If you start with $1$ then just shift everything up by $g_1+\dots+g_n$.)

Comment: I think you mean "$a_j < g_1$", not "$j < g_1$". With that change, it seems OK to me. Very nice. Upvoted.

Comment: @martycohen Thanks; I've corrected the typo you pointed out.